# Python requests_oauthlib OAUTH V2 BackendClient fetch_token() error

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, requests-oauthlib

I am attempting to use the BackendClient workflow for creating a OAUTH V2.0 connection. Using the requests_oauthlib package. Documentation is at: https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#backend-application-flow

The code works fine in PowerShell, but the equivalent in python is giving the error:

```
    token = session.fetch_token(token_url=tokenURL, client_id=ClientID, client_secret=secret)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\1455765990E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 251, in fetch_token
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Please supply either code or authorization_response parameters.
```

It makes no sense to ask for a response url (since this is a backend workflow) and the code is what the fetch_token is going to give, so I don't have one yet!

This is the PowerShell that works fine:

```
function GetToken($secret) {

    $uri = $LoginURL + $tenant + '/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    $body = @{
        "client_id" = $ClientID
        "scope" = "https://dod-graph.microsoft.us/.default"
        "username" = $tenant
        "password" = $client_secret
        "grant_type" = "client_credentials"
        "client_secret" = $secret
    } 
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    return $response
    $token = $response.access_token
    $exp = $response.expires_in
    $token
}
```

and this is what we think is the equivalent in Python

```
def getToken(store):
    """ Get OAUTH Token and session"""
    tokenURL = LoginURL + TenantID + '/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    scope = "https://dod-graph.microsoft.us/.default"
    client = oauthlib.oauth2.BackendApplicationClient(client_id=ClientID, scope=scope)
    session = requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(client)
    session.verify = False
    secret = store['secret']
    print(f"--token URL: {tokenURL}")
    token = session.fetch_token(token_url=tokenURL, client_id=ClientID, client_secret=secret)
    print(f"--token: {token}")
    return session
```

Answer (score 0):

First positional argument of requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session is `client_id` (str) but you pass `BackendApplicationClient`, so session client is `None` during call, and when it is none requests_oauthlib will use `WebApplicationClient` as a default.
To fix that just pass client by keyword argument:

```py
# --- snip ---
client = oauthlib.oauth2.BackendApplicationClient(client_id=ClientID, scope=scope)
session = requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(client=client)
# --- snip ---
```